# best data structure for below xml of book in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, data-structures

data.xml:

```html
<catalog abbrev="KJV" name="xyz">
<book num="Gen">
  <chapter num="1">
    <page num="1">In the beginning ...</page>
    <page num="2">And the earth .... </page>
  </chapter>
  <chapter num="2"><page num="1">.....</book>
<book>
```

I have to create hierarchical structure so user can navigate up or down dynamically.

Means first of all i have to show all title of book: which are attribute of book element then when user click on book title they will see list of all chapter..then next when click on chapter it will see verses list...then when click on particular verses they will see only single verses...

Comment: please show your work. break up your question into smaller questions. what first?

Comment: I have one xml file as shown in question. at home page i have to show only book title: which is as attribute of book elements in xml file.

Comment: in second page show list of chapter for selected book. after if user select specific chapter than show page list